# Adding node to TreeView with Angular 4 and ng2-tree framework

Tags: javascript, angular, web

So I'm pretty new to Angular and I started using ng2-tree for some project, but I have a problem which I don't understand how to solve.
This tree have "adding" method, but it doesn't change array of tree, so it doesn't really change and I can't store it at database.
Thanks.

```
import { Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NodeEvent, TreeModel, RenamableNode, Ng2TreeSettings } from 'ng2-tree';
import { ServerService } from "app/pages/components/components/treeView/storeService.service";
import alertify from 'alertify.js';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
declare const alertify: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-view',
  styleUrls: ['treeView.css'],
  templateUrl: 'treeView.html',
  providers: [ServerService],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class TreeView implements OnInit {
    constructor(private serverService: ServerService, private http: Http /*private treeview: TreeModel*/){
    }
    tree: TreeModel = {
    value: 'Programming languages by programming paradigm',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'Object-oriented programming',
        children: [
          {
            // I am a RenamableNode. Yeah, that's me :)
            value: <RenamableNode>{
              name: 'Java',
              setName(name: string): void {
                this.name = name;
              },
              toString(): string {
                return this.name;
              }
            }
          },
          {value: 'C++'},
          {value: 'C#'}
        ]
      },
      {
        value: 'Prototype-based programming',
        settings: {
          'static': true
        },
        loadChildren: (callback) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            callback([
              {value: 'JavaScript'},
              {value: 'CoffeeScript'},
              {value: 'TypeScript'}
            ]);
          }, 5000);
        }
      }
    ]
  };

    ngOnInit(){
        /*return this.http.get('https://testing-angular-50890.firebaseio.com/data.json').subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );*/
    }
    private static logEvent(e: NodeEvent, message: string): void {
        console.log(e);
        alertify.logPosition("top right");
        if((message==="Moved") || (message==="Renamed") || (message==="Created") || (message==="Selected")){
            alertify.success(`${message}: ${e.node.value}`);
        }
        else{
            alertify.error(`${message}: ${e.node.value}`);
        }

    }
    public onNodeRemoved(e: NodeEvent): void {
        TreeView.logEvent(e, 'Removed');
        this.http.put('https://testing-angular-50890.firebaseio.com/data.json', this.tree).subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
    }

    public onNodeMoved(e: NodeEvent): void {
        TreeView.logEvent(e, 'Moved');
        this.http.put('https://testing-angular-50890.firebaseio.com/data.json', this.tree).subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
    }

    public onNodeRenamed(e: NodeEvent): void {
        TreeView.logEvent(e, 'Renamed');
        this.http.put('https://testing-angular-50890.firebaseio.com/data.json', this.tree).subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
    }

    public onNodeCreated(e: NodeEvent): void {
        TreeView.logEvent(e, 'Created');
        this.http.put('https://testing-angular-50890.firebaseio.com/data.json', this.tree).subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
        console.log(e);
    }

    public onNodeSelected(e: NodeEvent): void {
        this.http.put('https://testing-angular-50890.firebaseio.com/data.json', this.tree).subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
        TreeView.logEvent(e, 'Selected');
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a small working example? Maybe a plunker or something like that?

Comment: It's actually pretty hard because of so many files and frameworks. I could post a codes, if this will be useful.

Comment: I added my code, I hope it's enough

Comment: any updates on this ?

Comment: Actually no. I went with jstree plugin for jquery for now